# Can I reuse the result of an expression inside an anonymous function?

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function

I have an anonymous function like `@(x) sqrt(x) + 1./sqrt(x) - 3` that I want to pass to another function, e.g.

```
fsolve(@(x) sqrt(x) + 1./sqrt(x) - 3, 3)
```

Imagine, the argument of `sqrt` is a little bit more complex and hence the `sqrt(...)` call is heavy to compute - would it be possible to create an anonymous function that computes (in this easy example) `sqrt(x)` first and then uses the result `res` for the computation of `res + 1/res - 3`?

Or can this be programmed only with a normal function?

Comment: one remark: I want to use this also for code generation (embedded coder), so I have to see which solutions are supported by the embedded coder..

Comment: You know `fsolve` needs a function handle, but it doesn’t need to be an anonymous function. You can write an actual function, which you can stick at the end of the M-file that uses it, and pass a handle to that.

Answer (score 6):

If your idea of *nested anonymous function* goes into the direction of "everything within a single anonymous function without intermediate steps" (i.e. intermediate anonymous functions), I can't think of a solution, since you have to somehow "store" the value to prevent its re-calculation. So, my idea would be the following:

```matlab
% Original function
orig = @(x) sqrt(x) + 1./sqrt(x) - 3;

% Complicated inner function
inner = @(x) sqrt(x);

% Actual function
func = @(y) y + 1./y - 3;

% Function wrapper
wrapper = @(z) func(inner(z));

% Some small tests
X = 1:10;
orig(X)
wrapper(X)

ans =
  -1.000000  -0.878680  -0.690599  -0.500000  -0.316718  -0.142262   0.023716   0.181981   0.333333   0.478505

ans =
  -1.000000  -0.878680  -0.690599  -0.500000  -0.316718  -0.142262   0.023716   0.181981   0.333333   0.478505
```

The complicated inner function is only evaluated once - at least, from my point of view.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this (although [whether this is really a neat solution to your real problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) may be up for debate).

You essentially want to define an inner anonymous function and then evaluate it immediately with the result of some expensive function call.

MATLAB handles defining an anonymous function inside an anonymous function definition exactly the way you'd expect the syntax to allow you. The "evaluate immediately" bit can be done using `feval`:

```
@(x) feval(@(res) res + 1./res - 3, sqrt(x))
```